# ul /li (list) not refreshing or updating in vue js autocomplete component?

Tags: html, vue.js, autocomplete

so i have created a new autocomplete component in vue js.(see code for this below)

main.js-

```
Vue.component('g-autocomplete', {
  props: ['value','title'],
  
  mixins: [viewMixin('g-autocomplete')],
  data() {
    return {
      input: ''
      
    }
  },
  template: ` <div class="autocomplete">
    <input style="font-size: 12pt; height: 36px; width:1800px; " type="text"  v-model="input"  @input="handleInput"/>
     <ul >
      <li v-for="(item, i) in filteredResults" :key="i" @click="setInput(item)" >
         <!-- {{ autocompleteData }} -->
          <template v-if="title!='manager'">
          <div class="container">
            <p>
              <b>ID:</b>
              {{item.id}}
            </p>
            <p>
              <b>Description:</b>
              {{item.description}}
            </p>
          </div>
        </template>
         <template v-else>
        <div class="container">
            <p>
              <b>ID:</b>
              {{item.id}}
            </p>
            <p>
              <b>First Name:</b>
              {{item.firstName}}
            </p>
            <p>
              <b>Last Name:</b>
              {{item.lastName}}
            </p>
          </div>
        </template>
           </li>
    </ul>
  </div>`,
  methods: {
    handleInput(e) {
      console.log('inside handleInput')
      this.$emit('input', e.target.value)
    },

    setInput(value) {
      console.log('inside setInput')
      this.input = value
      this.$emit('click', value)
    },

  },
  watch: {
    $props: {
      immediate: true,
      deep: true,
      handler(newValue, oldValue) {
        console.log('new value is'+newValue)
        console.log('old value is'+oldValue)
        console.log('value inside handler'+this.value)
    //    console.log('list inside handler'+this.list)
        console.log('title inside handler'+this.title)
       this.input=newValue.value

      }
    }
    // msg(newVal) {
    //     this.msgCopy = newVal;
    // }
}
})
```

the 'filteredResults' array is declared in the viewmixin.js like-

```
export const viewMixin = (viewName) => {
    return {
        data() {
            return {
                filteredResults: [],
                show:false,
               
            }
        },
 computed: 
           {
            viewData() {
                return this.$store.getters.getViewData(viewName)
            },
            objectData() {
                return this.$store.getters.getApiData(this.viewData.api_id).data
            },

}
---
---
}
}
```

.vue file where the component is used

```
   <b-field  label="Custom Business Unit">
      <g-autocomplete v-on:input="getAsyncDataBusinessUnit" v-on:click="(option) => {updateValue(option.id,'businessUnit')}" :value="this.objectData.businessUnit"  title='businessUnit' >
      </g-autocomplete>
</b-field>
```

the getAsyncDataBusinessUnit debounce method-

```
    getAsyncDataBusinessUnit: debounce(function(name) {
      console.log('1st line'+JSON.stringify(this.filteredResults))
      console.log('inside  getAsyncDataBusinessUnit ')
      if (!name.length) {
        this.show=false;
        this.filteredResults = [];
      
        return;
      }
      this.isFetching = true;
      api
        .getSearchData(this.sessionData.key,`/businessunit/?filter={id} LIKE '%25${name}%25' OR {description} LIKE '%25${name}%25'`)
        .then(response => {
          this.filteredResults = [];
          response.forEach(item => {
            this.filteredResults.push(item);
          });
          this.show=true;
          console.log('filtred results array is'+JSON.stringify(this.filteredResults))
        })
        .catch(error => {
          this.filteredResults = [];
          throw error;
        })
        .finally(() => {
          this.isFetching = false;
        });
    }, 500),
```

NOTE: I have added a console log in the debounce function and i can see the filteredResults array getting populated after the push operation.But for some reason i cant see the dropdown in the ui when i start to type something. I feel like the the list in the ui is not re-rendering/updating because in the console log i can see the data ie. the array of objects 'filteredResults'.So i think it is still picking up the old value (initial value) of 'filteredResults' as an empty array.  .Please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the mixin. It looks like your intention is to have the `g-autocomplete` component share the same reference to the `filteredResults` Array as does the `b-field` component. You are expecting that when `this.filteredResults` is assigned to in the `getAsyncDataBusinessUnit` method of the `b-field` component that the `g-autocomplete` component will re-render due to the change to `filteredResults` which is referenced in its template.

However, the `this.filteredResults` that is the `g-autocomplete` component has a reference to *is not the same `this.filteredResults`* that `b-field` has a reference to!

This is because the mixin is creating a new `data` function for each component it is mixed into. And each new `data` function returns a new Object with a new `filteredResults` property pointing to a new empty Array.

I would advise removing this mixin and adding `filteredResults` as a `prop` of g-autocomplete.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/wbq7sku3/) for your reference.

### Follow-up

Your `input` value is reset every time that the `g-autocomplete` component's `$props` Object is modified. Specifically, the line `this.input=newValue.value` in the watcher sets the value of `input` to the value of `objectData.businessUnit` in the parent. You have not included how/when `objectData.businessUnit` is assigned to, but since you are telling us that your input value gets reset, I can conclude that `objectData.businessUnit` does not get a new value when the `input` event is emitted from the `g-autocomplete` component.

I am not totally sure why you have the `$props` watcher; it may be to set the initial value of the `input` model. Regardless, the key to preventing the resetting of `input` would be to remove the `this.input=newValue.value` line from your watcher. If you want to set the intial value of `input` based on the `value` prop, you could do that in the `g-autocomplete`'s `created` hook - which will fire only once in the component's lifecycle, at creation. (This move may mean that you can remove your `$props` watcher entirely.

The code to be added to the `g-autocomplete` component would be:

```
created() {
    this.input=this.value;
}
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/wypq80tg/) is a new fiddle.

Comment: i have already tried making 'filteredResults' as a prop ie, i passed the array as a prop from the vue file to the g-autcomplete component.But the issue is whenever i start to type something in the input field, the input is immediately reset  because the filteredResults array is modified in the 'getAsyncDataBusinessUnit' debounce method.

Comment: so that is why i went with the view mixin approach.

Comment: so any idea on how to overcome this? Can you show me an example talking my 'getAsyncDataBusinessUnit' debounce method into consideration

Comment: i think the main issue here is if i use  'filteredResults' as a prop and then since  'filteredResults is getting modified in the  'getAsyncDataBusinessUnit' debounce method the g-autocomplete component  will refresh or  re-render  due to the change to filteredResults array and hence will reset the input before i could fully type anything into the input field.so how do i overcome since iam unable to type anything into the input field ?

Comment: thanks for the follow up!! .Just to answer you question, objectData is a computed property defined in the viewmix.js.I am using vuex store and the objectData computed property returns the data from there(the store).I have updated the question with those computed properties

Comment: and also in my case i have defined the  'getAsyncDataBusinessUnit' debounce method in the parent vue file and not in the 'g-autocomplete' component since  i want the child component(g-autocomplete) to be a presentational component and the calculation and every thing is taken care by the parent itself. Hence this is why iam using  this.$emit to emit the event back from the g-autocomplete component back to the parent vue file

Comment: @VigneshSwaminathan: Does my suggestions produce a working solution for you?

Comment: yes thank you very much . your solution really worked out for me.

Comment: there is just one more issue that iam facing which is the value coming from the store objectData.businessUnit is not getting set to the input field upon page load for already submitted form pages. Any idea on this issue? I have also tried using the created hook and setting the input with the prop value like you mentioned

Comment: just to remind you- objectData here is a computed property defined in the viewmixin.js.It returns the value of the input field from the store getters like-.$store.getters.

Comment: @VigneshSwaminathan: I don't understand your follow-up question. I think you should post a new question with the relevant code from the `$store`.